# \Is possible read file from client in a webService?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I need to read a file from client with a webservice. Is it possible?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4bnd.png)

Comment: Browsers can upload files, if that's what you mean... I'm afraid your question is pretty unclear, partly as it's so broad.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet 

I want read a file in the client pc through webservice, Without use webForm, only webService.  Its Possible?

there is some library?

Thanks

Comment: It's still very unclear what you're asking. Do you control software running on the client? If so, then yes - that client can send the contents of a local file as part of a web service request. That's not the web service reading the file - it's the *client* of the web service making a request...

Comment: There is no client, the file must be uploaded directly from the WebService. The user types the directory

Locally it works, but from the client computer can not find the file.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what web services are, I'm afraid. There's always a client - that's what sends the request. Hint: think about what the user is typing the directory name into. If it's a browser, then the browser is the client of the web service... and it's still the client that does the uploading, *not* the web service.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to confirm by someone else.   :)  (y)